# Square: How to integrate square in-app payment api with Xamarin.iOS and Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, square

I want to integrate square in-app payment in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. Is there any way to do this in Xamarin for both android and iOS cross platform application(Not the Xamarin forms please)? I have contacted Square support and they replied with "we don't support generation of a nonce through Xamarin, which is what we use to process a card.". But I need to integrate this in my app. Is there any other way without nonce.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to process online or in-app payments with Square is via a nonce. Currently, there's no Xamarin plugin available for the Square In-App Payments SDK. Since the SDK exists for both iOS and Android already, theoretically a plugin/wrapper could be built, but we don't offer support on making it work since we don't formally have a plugin already.

I'll share the feedback with our In-App Payments team in the meantime, though.